# CSS styling of path in cloned SVG

Tags: css, svg

I've tried using SVG cloning/templating using use:xlink (as [discussed here](http://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/)), but I don't seem to be able to use CSS to change the path of the cloned graphic to be different from the parent.

Hopefully [this pen](http://codepen.io/johnholtripley/pen/csimK) explains the problem.

Is there a way to do this? Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't think of the elements resulting from `<use xlink:href="#marker">` as copies. You're essentially referencing (re-displaying) the original template, and any changes to that template are going to reflect on all referenced instances.

The other thing is that those referenced instances are put in a document fragment that is not accessible by CSS. You cannot select the inner element of your instances with CSS. The styles given to the containing `svg` element are going to be applied to the outer shape of your template (which is why it works for the tutorial in  your question).

I recommend using CSS to create these objects: http://jsbin.com/ijElUZiG/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for this. It was looking like it couldn't be done, but it's good to have it confirmed.